# Unexpected behavior inside the foreachPartition method of a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I evaluated through the spark-shell the following lines of scala codes:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
val b = a.coalesce(1)
b.foreachPartition { p => 
  p.map(_ + 1).foreach(println)
  p.map(_ * 2).foreach(println)
}
```

The output is the following:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Why the partition *p* becomes empty after the first map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not look strange to me since *p* is *Iterator*, when you walk through it with map, it has no more values, and taking into account that *length* is shortcut for *size* which is implemented like this:

```
def size: Int = {
  var result = 0
  for (x <- self) result += 1
  result
}
```

you get 0.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the scala doc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Iterator. It explicitely states that an iterator (*p* is an iterator) must be discarded after calling on it the map method.